# База данных продажи жд билетов

Tags: sql, база-данных, er-diagram

Всего 13 таблиц:
1. Билет
2. Маршруты
3. Клиент
4. Поезд
5. Вагон
6. Вид вагона
7. Категория вагона
8. Класс обслуживания
9. Метод оплаты
10. Касса
11. Вокзал
12. Сотрудники
13. Должности
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как должна быть правильно построена ER-диаграмма?

Comment: Тут отсутствует самая важная для большинства пассажиров информация - на какое место билет: на верхнее или на нижнее? И зачем ссылка на маршрут присутствует и в сущности "поезд", и в сущности "билет"? Разве возможно такое, что поезд относится к маршруту 1, а билет на этот поезд - к маршруту 2?

Comment: Для решения подобных проблем ознакомитесь с НФ базы данных https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0